# Stale items displayed in component

Tags: reactjs

I have an app that displays some images. There are 12 images in total and each page displays 10 max. Number those images from 1 to 12, when change to page 2 you will see 2 wrappers showing image 1 and 2 instead of 11 and 12 for a very short time(you will get the right image eventually). This only happens when you change the page for the first time.
I'm confused about this behavior. [Here's my website](https://xn--9wys51efve.com/). And [here is the GitHub repo](https://github.com/Owlput/baimianxiao.com).
My guess is that it's related to how React schedules updates. Or maybe I implement this functionality wrongly. It's harmless but you will be upset to have this kind of experience browsing the web.

Here's the component. I leave out the css part and something not that relevant to make the code shorter.

```
export default function ThumbPage() {
  const thumbData = useDataFetch(target);
  const [page, setPage] = useState([1, 1]);
  const [timeSort, setTimeSort] = useState(1);
  const [thumbDisp, setThumbDisp] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setPage([1, thumbData ? Math.ceil(thumbData.length / 10) : 1]);
  }, [thumbData]);

  const changePage = (to) => {
    setPage([to, page[1]]);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    let a = thumbData?.slice((page[0] - 1) * 10, page[0] * 10);
    setThumbDisp(a);
  }, [thumbData, timeSort, page]);
  if (thumbDisp) {
    return (
      <div className="aliContV" style={{ minWidth: "80%" }}>
        <Paper>
          <div>
            <div>
              <FormControl fullWidth>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Time Ordering</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                  id="demo-simple-select"
                  value={timeSort}
                  label="TimeSort"
                  onChange={changeTimeSort}
                >
                  <MenuItem value={1}>New to Old</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={-1}>Old to New</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </div>
            <div>
              {thumbDisp ? (
                thumbDisp.map((image, index) => (
                  <ImageCard {...image} key={index}></ImageCard>
                ))
              ) : (
                <></>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
          <PageSelector
            parentChangePage={changePage}
            maxPage={page[1]}
          ></PageSelector>
        </Paper>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <CircularProgress />;
  }
}
```

Comment: please share the relevant code here as part of your question

Comment: @thedude I'll take care of that and pay more attention next time. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
 <ImageCard {...image} key={index}></ImageCard>
```

Don't use `index` as the key for `ImageCard`.
Replace it with the image URL or something that identifies the image.

Comment: OK problem resolved. Since the key doesn't change it's content won't get updated until a rerender is triggered else where. I know it's bad idea to use index as the key but I didn't see this coming.  I'm sorry that I didn't point out the exact code to have you analyzing my crap. Thank you very much!